# Kafka topic and configurations and issue after deployment

Tags: apache-kafka

Once the application is deployed, it will automatically creates the topic with the configurations,

```
datatransmit.minioSubJobTopic=datatransmit.asset.subjobs.upload 
datatransmit.noOfConsumerInstance=3
datatransmit.corePoolSize=20
datatransmit.maxPoolSize=10
datatransmit.queueCapacity=300
datatransmit.sizeOfPage=1000
```

In the Second deployment if any changes made in the configurations of the existing topic like ,

```
datatransmit.noOfConsumerInstance=10
datatransmit.corePoolSize=40
```

and so on....

it is not reflecting the changes, so this application is basically able to create a configuration for the first time ,but if this application wants to modify existing  Topic Configurations, then the second time it is not reflecting the changes made rather it reflects the old configuration itself

Comment: Please clarify what config file this is. Kafka has no such features out of the box

Comment: So, Spring? You also have MinIO referenced? I searched the web for `noOfConsumerInstance`, and I see no references to this field anywhere. Besides, the properties you've mentioned are not related to topic configurations at all, but rather seem to be your own app's custom Consumer properties, using any existing topics you've subscribed to

Comment: See docs for more details - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs

Comment: Yes you are right,these are our own custom topic configurations, so is there any way to get the changes done to these custom topic configurations and get reflected after post kafka deployment

Comment: Again, none of these properties are valid topic configurations, so no? You can't have custom ones. Those are all defined by the server, not your app. You need to use Kafka AdminClient to manually update topic configs when your app starts